# unable to load CRM organization

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I can't connect to the V9 on premise env with plugin registration tool, I'm getting the error: Unable to load the CRM organization.

I have searched similar questions but my issue is not similar, stack trace doesn't mention anything releated to the user or to the role.

Can you give me an advice ?

stack trace(details of the error):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.CrmPluginStep.RefreshFromSdkMessageProcessingStep(Guid assemblyId, SdkMessageProcessingStep step, String secureConfig)
at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.OrganizationHelper.LoadSteps(CrmOrganization org, Dictionary`2 typeList, Dictionary`2& crmStepList)
at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.Helper.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<OpenConnection>b__0(Object o, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

Comment: did you try with the Plugin Registration inside XrmToolBox?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes, I can load the organization and see all it's plugins from XrmToolbox > Plugin Registration tool

Comment: then use XrmToolBox version or download a previous nuget package of the official Plugin Registration Tool, being your instance onpremise IFD must be configured correctly probably

Comment: @GuidoPreite I have tried the previous version of Plugin Registration tool as well but still no luck there. What might be the issue with the on prem configuration that might cause such an issue ?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Actually, you are right I downgraded to the first ever version of Plugin Registration tool and I was able to connect to the organization and perform all the necessary operations. Thanks for that, write it as an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the instance is OnPremise several issues can be the cause why the latest version of the Plugin Registration Tool is not able to connect, main one can be IFD not configured correctly.

In order to connect to the instance a user can:

- Use the Plugin Registration Tool inside XrmToolBox

or

- Use a previous version of the Plugin Registration Tool downloading the nuget package and extract it

Comment: Plugin registration inside the XrmToolbox get's the job done, but in my case I needed to debug the plugin so I did also get an older version of Plugin Registration tool from nuget and it solved an issue, thanks